# Javascript error when calling AngularFirestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying once again to use Angular and Firebase on my projects.

I want to make a 2 pages website, where basically the home page is static and the  second page is a blog using firestore, exactly as described on the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md).

*"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
"firebase": "^5.0.4",*

I have no error when I compile, but as soon as I add this line : 
    constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {}

the page doens't display and I get this weird error :

> ERROR TypeError: **webpack_require**.i(...) is not a function at firestore.js:28

I have uninstalled / installed dozens of different versions of angularfire2, including AngularFire2@4...,  but nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to help you unless you provide a demo. Can you use http://www.stackblitz.com to create a demo and I'll be happy to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all imports are right and initialized and if possible, post your `package.json "dependencies":`

```
app.module.ts

...
imports:[
...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
...
];
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,

  firebase: {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    ...
  }
};
```